# How To find position of nested list in list in python

Tags: python, nested-lists

so if I've got a nested list, What is the best way to find the position of the nested list.

```
x=[12.011, [1.007, 2, 15.999], 4]
index=x.index(list)
```

The expected output would be `[1]`, but I can only get errors.

Comment: iterate over the list, check the type of the item, if it is a list, break and you have your index. `for i,e in enumerate(x): if type(e) is list: break` then `i` will be the index

Comment: If you've got errors, show them. Also, what's the definition of `list`? Or is it the case that you want to get it by type? If that's the case, what should happen when you have multiple lists in the main list? Provide more detail for people to be able to actually help.
See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What *problem do you solve* by finding this index? What do you hope to do with the index?

Comment: You could loop over the list thanks to `enumerate()` and define the position of the (first) element you're looking for. Keep in mind it's one of element among potentially several ones, it depends on your context and what you are precisely looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=[12.011, [1.007, 2, 15.999], 4]

for i in x:
    if type(i) == list:
        print(x.index(i))
```

This will help you.

```
x=[12.011, [1.007, 2, 15.999], 4, [1, 2]]

y = list(i for i, j in enumerate(x) if type(j) == list)
print(y)
```

This will make a list of indices.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
>>> [type(i) for i in x].index(list)
1
>>>
```

Or:

```
>>> [i for i, v in enumerate(x) if isinstance(v, list)]
[1]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `next` to short-circuit:

```
next(n for n, i in enumerate(x) if isinstance(i, list))
```

Output:

```
1
```